# Show that H is normal subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let H be a proper subgroup of G and  a $\in$ G, a $\notin$ H. Suppose that for all b $\in$ G, either b $\in$ H, or Ha = Hb. Show that H is normal subgroup of G. How do I proceed on this?

Comment: What do you mean by b $\in$, or Ha = Hb ?

Comment: I guess he meant "either $\;b\in H\;$ or $\;Ha=Hb\;$ , making $\;H\;$ a subgroup of index two and thus normal...?

Comment: Yes, thats I what I meant.. Why will a subgroup of index 2 always be normal?

Comment: Question has been asked, and answered, several times on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of $H$ in $G$ is two that is it has exactly two right/left cosets, specifically $$ \{H, Ha\}$$ $$ \{H , a'H\} $$

Since the right/left cosets define equivalence classes $$ Ha = G \setminus H = a'H$$

Hence every left coset of $H$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G$ whence $H \triangleleft G $.

---